# why use bootstrap css as a package in laravel?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, composer-php

I am using laravel framework and have been using jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap by saving it under public/assets/

example:-

```
public/assets/js/bootstrap.js
public/assets/js/jquery.js

public/assets/css/bootstrap.css
public/assets/css/style.css
```

Why should I prefer using it from composer packages, is there any advantage of doing in this way?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't. Unless the package includes helper functions as a shortcut to creating Bootstraps HTML elements in your views, front end packages would probably be better handled manually, or by a front end package manager like grunt.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is totally up to you. The main advantage with using composer is the ease of updating bootstrap as the code base is updated. All you have to do is run a composer update